# $R$-points on a variety: explain to me like I'm 5

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If I have an affine variety $X$ in $K^n$, and a subring $R$ in $K$, $X(R)$, the set of $R$-points, is just $X \cap R^n$, by definition (right?).  What is the highbrow way to view $X(R)$ so it doesn't depend on the imbedding of $X$ in $K^n$?  And in what sense is the resulting definition independent of the imbedding? Do you have to use the word "scheme" to explain it to me? Its ok if you do, but I barely know anything about schemes except the definition -- though i'm generally ok (not great) with classical affine algebraic geometry

Comment: To the first line, in general no. An affine variety is defined over some thing, usually a filed, say $k$. Then only $R$ for which $X(R)$ makes sense is when $R$ is a $k$-algebra. You do not need schemes to define these, just some knowledge of commutative rings (very little at that).

Comment: @Mohan Thank you. So for instance, though, I hear people talk about $X(\mathbb{Z})$ for an affine variety $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, I think things are a bit mors complicated in this down-to-earth question. For example if you consider in $\mathbb R^3$ the variety $\pi x^3-\pi y^5+ez^2=0$ it makes perfect sense to say that it has as solution over $\mathbb Z$ the triple $(1,1,0)$ even though $\mathbb Z$ is not an $\mathbb R$-algebra.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, of course, but that is not what one means by $X(R)$, at least in the usual language.

Comment: Dear @Mohan,  Of course I agree with you about the usual language but I think the OP is in search of some abstract but non scheme-theoretic definition  which would yield $X[R]=X(K)\cap R^n$ in the case of an affine $K$-variety $X$  embedded into $\mathbb A^n_K$. And one certainly  should change notations (as I have done) in order to avoid a clash with the usual  scheme-theoretic notation $X(R)$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg yes, thanks, thats what i was hoping for. I mean certainly people talk about $X(\mathbb{Z})$ (dont they?) so its not *strictly* true that we need $R$ to be a $k$ algebra.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg  If  you want solutions to some specified equations in a ring $R$, it is better to say that than use $X(R)$, which is co-ordinate independent and thus if you change coordinates of $K^n$, $X(R)$ is not expected to change, but what you say will.

Comment: @user520642 see my comment above to Georges.

Comment: @Mohan so you're saying there is no coordinate independent notion of $X(\mathbb{Z})$ even if $X$ is defined by elements of $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. If $X$ is defined by polynomials in the ring you write, by definition, it is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ and so $X(\mathbb{Z})$  makes sense (independent of co-ordinates).

Comment: @Mohan Ok, so one may speak of $X(R)$ (for $X\subset K^n$, where $K$ is some field containing the ring $R$) so long as $X$ is defined by polynomials over $R$?

Comment: $K$ is unimportant. If $X$ is defined by polynomials over $R$, $X(R)$ makes sense  independent of coordinates as I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume for now that $K$ is alg. closed and $R$ is a subfield of $K$.

We know that $X$ is affine, and $X$ is defined by $(f_1,...,f_p)$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Take $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ a point in $X$.
You get a $K$-linear map $K[T_1,...,T_n]\to K$ mapping $T_i$ to $a_i$. Saying that $a$ is on $X$ is saying that this map factors through $K[T_1,...,T_n]\to K[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_p)\to K$. In other words giving a point of $X$ is giving a $K$-algebra morphism from $A_K=K[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_p)$ to $K$.

Now assume that such a morphism is given. You can look at the image $T_i$ in $K$ and this gives you an $a_i$ and $(a_1,...,a_n)$ is an element of $X$ (as $f_k(a_i)$ has to be zero). Thus you can view points of $X$ as $K$-morphisms from $A_K$ to $K$.

To prove that the correspondence defined is a bijection you may use the Nullstellensatz.

Let us assume now that the polynomials are defined over $k$ which is a subfield of $R$ (it may be $R$). Giving a $K$-morphism from $A$ to $K$ is the same thing as giving a $k$-morphism from $A_k=k[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_i)$ to $K$. This morphism may, or may not land in $R$. If it does, in particular the point you get in $X$ will have "coordinates" in $R$ (recall the construction). In other words if the polynomials are defined over $k$, a point with coefficients in $R$ is a $k$-morphism from $A_k$ to $R$. Or an $R$-morphism from $A_R$ to $R$.

To sum up, if your polynomials are defined over $k$, the points of the variety in $K^n$ which have coefficients in $R$ are identified with $k$-morphisms $A_k\to R$. But every $k$-automorphism of $A_k$ will map bijectively such automorphisms to themselves. In other words it only depends on the structure of $A_k$ as a $k$-algebra.

Comment: If $R$ is merely a subring of $K$ this may fail in the genral (e.g projective) case. And in fact you can shut out $K$ of the picture at all... If your variety is defined over $k$ and you have an extension $R/k$ the $k$ morphisms $A_k \to R$ corresponds to the solutions of the defining equations which are in $R$ (use the previous thing in an alg closure of $R$).

Comment: Thanks that makes complete sense. So then there's no real coordinate invariant way to talk about "integer points" on $X$ (since the ring of integers may not contain the base field)?

Comment: You can of course talk about integral points but for this your variety needs to be "defined over $\mathbb{Z}$", which is to say that your polynomials have integral coefficients. However if everything works nicely in the affine case, in the projective case integral points (or $R$-points) might not work exactly as you think they do.

Comment: Thanks again. So just to be clear, in Diophantine geometry people regularly say something like, for instance, "Let $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine algebraic variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose the set of integral points $X(\mathbb{Z})$ is Zariski dense."  So in this case, this notion of $X(\mathbb{R})$ has no higher-brow coordinate invariant interpretation, correct?

Comment: oh wait, "defined over $\mathbb{Q}$" is the same as "defined over $\mathbb{Z}$"!

Comment: sorry, I meant $X(\mathbb{Z})$, not $X(\mathbb{R})$. But yeah I think I'm good. thanks again